# Batch File FLOAT math

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to create a batch that will calculate a certain equation with Input variables.
equation is

```
(%b%+(%b%*(88/100))+(%b%*(165/100))+(%b%*(%r%/100)))*%c%
```

im currently using code i found here but it doesn't seem to work properly

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
echo Enter BaseCC
set /P b=
echo Enter Riven ( if none enter 1 )
set /P r=
echo Enter Combo Multiplier
set /P c=
call :calc_ 2 (%b%+(%b%*(88/100))+(%b%*(165/100))+(%b%*(%r%/100)))*%c%
echo !calc_v!
pause
goto :EOF
:calc_
set scale_=1
set calc_v=
for /l %%i in (1,1,%1) do set /a scale_*=10
set /a "calc_v=!scale_!*%2"
set /a calc_v1=!calc_v!/!scale_!
set /a calc_v2=!calc_v!-!calc_v1!*!scale_!
set calc_v=!calc_v1!.!calc_v2!
goto :EOF
```

if b is 20; r is 114; c is 3
result should be 280.2

The result i get is 180.0

Comment: Batch files are absolutely not the correct tool for floating point math. I would suggest you instead seek solutions using [tag:powershell], and for that you'd need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57637145/edit) to include that tag.

Comment: use (the help of) another language, which can actually handle floating point numbers. You can find some useful examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279287/how-do-calculation-of-decimal-numbers-in-cmd) (vbscript).

Comment: im using Batch because it's the simplest one to use.

Comment: Not for this task it isn't. You've even proven it by using [tag:vbscript] for the math in your since posted solution!

Comment: By simplest i meant the commands are basic, no compile required and i don't need any additional apps. But yea, sometimes it can be inept at simple tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to the suggestions of  Stephan.
it works correctly now.
Didn't know i can implement vbs.

```
@echo off
set /p b=BaseCC= 
set /p r=Riven= 
set /p c=Combo= 
echo WSH.Echo Eval(Wscript.Arguments(0))>>Q.vbs
cscript //nologo Q.vbs ((%b%+(%b%*(88/100))+(%b%*(165/100))+(%b%*(%r%/100)))*%c%)
Del "Q.vbs"
Pause>nul
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem equation is (%b%+(%b%*(88/100))+(%b%*(165/100))+(%b%*(%r%/100)))*%c%

echo Enter BaseCC
set /P b=
echo Enter Riven ( if none enter 1 )
set /P r=
echo Enter Combo Multiplier
set /P c=

:: Calculate (%b%+(%b%*(88/100))+(%b%*(165/100))+(%b%*(%r%/100)))*%c%
:: write this in FP terms : (b+0.88b+1.65b+(br/100))*c
:: Resolve to (3.53b+(br/100))*c = (353b+br)*c/100
:: = (353+r)*b*c /100

SET /a result_by_100=(353+r)*b*c
ECHO result=%result_by_100:~0,-2%.%result_by_100:~-2%

GOTO :EOF
```

The problem is that the term `(%b%+(%b%*(88/100))+(%b%*(165/100))+(%b%*(%r%/100)))*%c%` is resolved using integer-maths, so each term which implements a division is resolved to `int(term)`. The result is `(%b%+(%b%*INT(88/100))+(%b%*INT(165/100))+(%b%*INT(%r%/100)))*%c%

The simple solution is to resolve the formula as shown.